# Can't find the $ Prompt in Unix

Tags: unix

I am very new to the Unix programming. Can anyone help me to find the $ prompt to type the next command, because I gave like cat advance.txt | less but I can't see the $ prompt.

Comment: Show output of `echo $PS1`. Your prompt does not have contain `$` although it's quite common.

Answer (score 1):

`less` is a program that open a new view and you have to quit typing `q`

Comment: Thankyou Very Much....it worked fine...but after typing q its showing 2 lines of that $ prompt..May i know why this is like this?

Comment: Every time when you type enter appears a new line in the terminal. I think you should check tutorials or articles to understand the terminals. You can start from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-the-linux-terminal). Please search in google and learn and then ask here for more specific questions.